Help identifying a terror series that looks like an older version of the X Files
When I was young, I used to watch a terror/fantasy series that was in the vein of the X Files, but before that show was aired.
From what I can recall, the series seems to be from the late 80's early 90's and it is about a paranormal investigator/parapsychologist that teams up with a woman that, as far as I can remember, was a lawyer or a psychologist. If I'm not mixing the X Files here, the formula was similar, he was the one that believed in the paranormal and she was the skeptic and they encountered the classic monster of the week in each episode.
... Buuut the most important thing is that she was bitten by a werewolf at the begining of the series and in a lot of episodes the monster of the week was defeated by her transforming into a werewolf at the last minute. This is foggy, but they might be searching for the werewolf that had bitten her, but I'm not sure about that. 
I remember watching that series and also the one called Werewolf from 1979 but the one I'm looking for looked a bit more recent.

"he was the one that believed in the paranormal and she was the skeptic"  Was that before or after she became a werewolf?

As long as I can remember (I may be wrong), she was like: "psh, ok, werewolves exist, but saquatch is a scam"; and the next week she was like "ok, sasquatch AND werewolves exist but, vampires? c'mon" and so on :P

This is "She-Wolf" of London. The female lead was a werewolf teamed up with a stodgy professor type. Ran in the early 90s for a few episodes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-Wolf_of_London
IMDb.com summary:

American graduate student Randi Wallace travels to Britain to study
  mythology with Professor Ian Matheson. She arrives expecting a stodgy
  old academic, but Ian is young, and the two are immediately attracted
  to one other. That complication quickly pales when Randi spends a
  night camping on the Moors and is bitten by a werewolf. For the rest
  of the series, Randi and Ian investigate supernatural phenomena
  together while they search for a cure for Randi's curse. Eventually,
  their search takes them from British academia to American television,
  when they move back to Randi's native California, and Ian becomes host
  of a trashy television talk show focusing on psychic phenomena. The
  series was an old-style romantic comedy with a touch of horror.


Ack people keep beating me to the punch today....
